# Chrome doesn't hide overflow for object with border-radius and backface-visibility:hidden

Tags: google-chrome, 3d, transform, css

I want to do a 3D card flip, but on a circle. So I create an element with

```
border-radius: 50% 
backface-visibility:hidden.
```

Everything works fine in firefox (22), but not in chrome (27.0.1453.116 m).

Here is a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gRuXR/1/

The first circle has backface visibility:hidden There you can see the contents coming out of the circle. The second circle has no backface-vsibility:hidden. There (in chrome) the front is shown correctly, but the back isn't.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a webkit bug?

Comment: be more specific...what is coming out of the circle...the text which is coming out of the circle is this your problem ??

Comment: The content of the circle, in this case it is indeed the text. I don't see how that is ambiguous or unclear.